# Setup an app container in App.js file in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, navigation-drawer, appcontainer

I am trying to make a login screen and after the login screen, it should take to home screen with drawer navigation. I am trying to set up the app container in the App.js file so, I am having trouble with it.

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <AppContainer />
  );
}


const DrawerNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  <NavigationContainer independent = {true}>
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="">
      <Drawer.Screen name="" component = "">
      <Drawer.Screen name="" component = "">
      <Drawer.Screen name="" component = "">
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
})

const AuthNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Auth: AuthScreen
})

const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: AuthNavigator,
  AppScreen: DrawerNavigator
})

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default App;
```

Comment: What is the error or trouble you are having? And in `Drawer.Screen` pass the component and name you have passed empty string that might have break the app for you.

Comment: App.js: Unexpected token (97:4)

   95 |
   96 | const DrawerNavigator = createStackNavigator({
>  97 |     <NavigationContainer independent = {true}>

Comment: No, I have just deleted them for purpose. I have passed the name and component as well. It is showing the error above.

Comment: I think you are using v4 of `react-navigation`. There is no `NavigationContainer` in v4.